# How do I redirect a subdomain to a different domain?

Tags: .htaccess, dns, http-status-code-301, forwarding

How do I redirect this:

**www.sub.example.com**

to this:

**www.example2.com**

How is this done -- 301? .htaccess? Can someone point me in the right direction please? My host is NearlyFreeSpeech and the domain I want to redirect to is quite a large site with a static IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

- If you have control of the domain, you can use a [CNAME record](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/CNAME_record) provided by your DNS server.
- In Apache, you can specify a [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) or [`RedirectPermanent`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectperm) directive in your Apache configuration files (*httpd.conf, .htaccess,* etc.)
- In Apache, you can specify a reverse proxy via the [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive. [Here's some documentation detailing this solution.](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)

Other solutions are possible, and generally vary by server and configuration stack. I assume Apache compliance, given the presence of *.htaccess* in the problem statement.

[Here's a Wikipedia reference on redirects via the 3xx family of HTTP status codes,](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/URL_redirection) if anyone's curious about the client's perspective.

Comment: Well I'm quite familiar with CNAME records, since I had to modify them to set up Google Apps. So, I think I'll follow this route. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it

```
RedirectPermanent / http://www.example2.com
```

`RedirectPermanent` would return a 301 code and force the client to go to www.example2.com, it works in apache config file and `.htaccess` file. You need `mod_alias` enabled to use it.

You can use this on the root directory of the subdomain in a `.htaccess` file, or in the virtualhost section of your apache configuration file.

For your reference the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent)

Comment: Where does this go? Sorry- I'm a little new to all this.

Comment: @yatman: depend how his your setup but the easiest would probably create a .htaccess on the root directory of your subdomain website and add the directive of my answer